Quantify differences between proposing a single prompt multiple times and proposing one prompt that requires multiple answers
In brief:
in what differ the probability of getting different results to prompting "write two instances of a given set" with respect to prompting two times "write an instance of a given set"?
Case study:
propose two times the same prompt:
prompt $\mathcal P=$ "Write an instance of a mammal"
response $r_1=$ "Lion"
prompt $\mathcal P=$ "Write an instance of a mammal"
response $r_2=$ "Dolphin"
propose one prompt to get two answers:
prompt $\mathcal P_{1,2}=$ "Write two instances of a mammal"
responses $r_1=$ "Elephant" and $r_2=$ "Giraffe"
In general:
Is there a way to relate $\mathbb P\{R_1=r_1,\, R_2=r_2\,|\, \mathcal P_{1,2}\}$ to $\mathbb P\{R=r_1\,|\, \mathcal P\}$ and $\mathbb P\{R=r_2\,|\, \mathcal P\}$?
Just playing with the multiplication rule and the theorem of total probability seams pointless. Thus, properties of (L)LMs have to be considered for answering the question.
Usefulness of the question:
On one hand, assuming the LLM is not learning from the conversation, Temperature and Top_p are the only parameters that have an impact on diversity/creativity when prompting a given sentence multiple times (e.g., $\mathcal P$ in the case study). Am I wrong?
On the other hand, asking with one prompt (e.g., $\mathcal P_{1,2}$ in the case study) multiple responses allows to exploit natural language (compared to numerical values as Temperature or Top_p) to qualify the required diversity. For instance, in the case study prompting $\mathcal P^{\prime}_{1,2}=$ "Write two instances of a mammal that are as diverse as possible" seams more specific.
Related question:
Does considering zero-shot vs few-shot prompts help in answering the previous question?
Interesting conversation about the subject with ChatGPT 3.5:
https://chatgpt.com/share/d1188c49-4f3f-4f6b-b4ad-a282494da583
